# How do I translate "hate speech"?

Tags: translation

As a moderator of a [Telegram group](https://www.telegramo.org), I once had to block a user.

What words can I use to translate "hate speech"? Here's a definition: Speech that attacks groups because of their ethnic origin, sexual orientation, religion, gender etc. 
I want to clarify that it isn't allowed, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two possibilities:

- *malama parolado* — hate speech
- *minacodiskurso* — threatening discourse

The first one is straightforward and the one readers will find easiest to recognize. The second is my attempt at a more direct term, covering threatening material of most kinds. (*Diskurso* can be used in Esperanto for the abstract term *discourse*.) Below are some related phrases.

- *rasa kalumniado* — racial vilification
- *genta kalumniado* — vilification of a group
- *instigado al diskriminacio* — promotion of discrimination
- *rasisma insultado/incitado* — racist abuse

Comment: Kvankam mi mem proponis la vorton „hatparolo” mi forte subtenas „kalumniado”. Vi povus diri: ĉia formo de kalumniado estas malpermesita - la gvidanto blokos tiujn personojn, kiuj kalumnias.

Answer (score 5):

Is there much wrong with simply *fiparolado*?

Comment: _fiparoli_ appears in the Reta Vortaro as _paroli maldece, malĝentile, vulgare_. This sounds more like speaking about rude topics and using a lot of swear words rather than speech that is aimed at harming a person or a group of people.

Answer (score 5):

Mi opinias, ke ne temas simple pri *kalumnio* (malutila mensogado) aŭ esprimo de sia *malamo*, sed pri dissemado de malamo, disvastigo de mistaksaj kvazaŭfaktoj, incitado, agreso kaj agresemo, atakoj kaj atakemo. Do vortoj kiel *ataka, agresa, incita, kverela parolo* estas eblaj.

Mi opinias, ke la plej bona resumo de ĉio ĉi estas la pure Esperantaj esprimoj *malpaca parolo* aŭ *malpacigado*. Ne provu traduki la vorton *malpaco*, ĉar vi eble ne tuj trovas evidentan tradukon en via lingvo. Pensu pri la vorto en Esperanto.

Comment: Dankegon! Jes, vi pravas. Mi sxategas "malpacigado"!

Answer (score 4):

This is another case where it makes sense to pause and reflect that we should focus on expressing ideas, not on translating words. What is the idea we're trying to express? Is this a universal idea? How can I express the idea in Esperanto?

As I think about it in these terms, the first thought that strikes me is that it's not always clear - even with this definition - what "hate speech" really is. I also recall that this is an expression that English lived very well without till just a few years ago.

As a moderator, it is ultimately you who define whether any particular speech is actual "hate speech" - and this is true regardless of what language you define it in, or what term you use for it.

My suggestion is to try to say what it is that you're trying to say without thinking in terms of "hate speech." If that doesn't work, translate the expression literally (*malam-parolado*) and be prepared to define it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I explained what I felt was inappropriate for the group and didn't use any specific term. I was also thinking about recurring "negative, aggressive and violent language".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there is a common used word yet, but in my opinion you can translate it literally: *hatparolo*.

-[Parolo](http://vortaro.net/#paroloj) = Unu aŭ pluraj vortoj, esprimantaj senton aŭ penson.

-[Hati](http://vortaro.net/#hati) = Forte malami.

→ hatparolo = Unu aŭ pluraj vortoj, esprimantaj forte malaman senton aŭ penson.